# Making a calculator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

My problem is that I can click and input multiple numbers for my first value but then after I used a math operator (ex. +,-,*,/) it only allows me to input a single value unlike the first time running it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    var secondNumber: Double = 0;
    var firstNumber: Double = 0;
    var performingMath = false
    var operatorUsed = 0;


    @IBAction func cleartext(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Label.text = ""
        performingMath = false
    }

    @IBAction func Numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if performingMath {
            Label.text = String(sender.tag - 1)
            secondNumber = Double(Label.text!)!
            performingMath = true
        } else {
            Label.text = Label.text! + String(sender.tag - 1)
            secondNumber = Double(Label.text!)!
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Operators(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if Label.text != " " && sender.tag != 11 {
            firstNumber = Double(Label.text!)!

            if sender.tag == 12 {
                Label.text = "+"
            } else if sender.tag == 13 {
                Label.text = "-"
            } else if sender.tag == 14 {
                Label.text = "*"
            } else if sender.tag == 15 {
                Label.text = "/"
            }
            operatorUsed = sender.tag
            performingMath = true
        } else if sender.tag == 11 {
            if operatorUsed == 12 {
                Label.text = String(firstNumber + secondNumber)
            } 
            if operatorUsed == 13 {
                Label.text = String(firstNumber - secondNumber)
            }
            if operatorUsed == 14 {
                Label.text = String(firstNumber * secondNumber)
            }
            if operatorUsed == 15 {
               Label.text = String(firstNumber / secondNumber)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the that I can input many values as possible after I used a math operator (ex. +-*/)

Comment: Unrelated to your issues but please note that it is common practice to name variables, functions, and enum cases starting with lowercase letters. Class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the label's text when `performingMath` is `true`, you just assign the new value instead of adding the value to the existing one (see line 3)

```
@IBAction func Numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if performingMath {
        Label.text = String(sender.tag - 1) // !! HERE !!
        secondNumber = Double(Label.text!)!
        performingMath = true
    } else {
        Label.text = Label.text! + String(sender.tag - 1)
        secondNumber = Double(Label.text!)!
    }
}
```

This should perform the same action as when `performingMath` is `false`, so you just need to update this line with:

```
Label.text = Label.text! + String(sender.tag - 1)
```